# Method to record tables used in transactions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have an Oracle 11g database and I have a desire to record which tables are used in transactions over a long period (indefinitely, realistically).

Our db is littered with unused tables, views, procedures, etc and I figured this would be an easy way to at least have a foundation for where to start cleaning up the tables.

I've found that I can view transactions with v$locked_object, but it is not allowable to create triggers on SYS tables.

Is there a method to handle this desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oracle audit log can be configured to do exactly what you want with minimal overhead.  See the [official details here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107).

Some steps to take which must be done with a user with DBA role or SYS as SYSDBA are:

- ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trail=db SCOPE=SPFILE;
- decide what objects you wish to monitor with a statement like AUDIT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON Yourschema.YourTable BY ACCESS;

I found this [article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/auditing-enhancements-11gr2) which goes into how to get around some issues that can arise to be very useful.

Things to note:

- you should move the audit log table to the SYSAUX or other tablespace so if it fills up the SYS tablespace your database does not crash
- be specific about what you want to audit.  Audit logs can get quite large
- a regular schedule of moving log files to secondary storage or deleting what you don't need is advised

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I'm not proficient as a dba so I apologize if this was an ignorant question.  Definitely appreciate the guidance and thorough answer.